# Transition css being lost upon ajax call

Tags: css, ajax

I have the following css on a div:

```
.action-dialog.is-active {
transform: translateX(0);
transition: 0.4s all ease-in-out; }
```

However upon ajax call the css transition is being lost, ie my pop up is not being displayed with a sliding effect.
Please any help?

The ajax call:

```
$("body").on("click", ".displayToDoDetails", function (e) {
$(e.currentTarget).addClass("is-active");
var notId = $(this).find(".toDoId").val();
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/DisplayToDoDetails/?qid=' + $('body').data('usid') + "&notId=" + notId,
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#toDoDetails").html(data);
        componentHandler.upgradeDom();
        return true;
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("An error occurred while displayind to do details");
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

HTML code:

```
<div class="action-dialog action-dialog--position-top action-dialog--fixed-width-lg js-action-dialog action-list__menu is-active">
<div class="mdl-card custom-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <div class="close js-action-dialog__close">
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text p-30">
        <h2 class="form__section-title--icon mb-20 text-transform-none font-r-bold font-size-lg--24">
            <i class="@Model.Icon mr-10"></i> @Model.Label
        </h2>

        <a href="@Model.URL" title="@Model.Label">View @Model.Label.ToLower()</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your ajax request code, is that call asynchronous or not?

Comment: @BearNithi :  I have added the ajax call.

Comment: please share your html

Comment: @BearNithi : Done

Comment: in your html you have already added is-active class, so the transition won't happen when you add it second time. i think you should remove the class and then add it accordingly.

Comment: @BearNithi: If i don t add is is-active the pop up is not displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188327/discussion-between-bear-nithi-and-tabby).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not setting up the transition properly. Transitions are typically arranged in the base state, and triggered once something changes (like the addition or subtraction of a class). For example:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const actionDialog = document.querySelector(".action-dialog");

function handleClick() {
  actionDialog.classList.toggle("is-active");
  actionDialog.querySelector("em").innerHTML = actionDialog.classList.contains("is-active") ? "active" : "inactive";
}

button.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  position: relative;
}

.box span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1.5em;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Once the 'is-active' class is removed, transition back 
   to the starting position */
.action-dialog {
  transform: translateX(0);
  /* Here we define what will happen when a change occurs */
  transition: 0.4s all ease-in-out;
}

/* Occurs only when the class is added */
.action-dialog.is-active {
  transform: translateX(300px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box action-dialog">
  <span>State: <em>inactive</em></span>
</div>

<button>Toggle action</button>
```

**Edit** In your comment, you asked:

> Is there a way to set the transition when the pop up is displayed?

I would create an animation and immediately apply it. The animation happens right away without the need for a class to be added or removed.

For example:

```css
.action-dialog {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: 1s move-dialog forwards;
}

@keyframes move-dialog {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  
  to {
  transform: translateX(200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="action-dialog"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the transition when the pop up is displayed?

Comment: @tabby Sure. For something immediate, I would use an animation.

Comment: @tabby I added an animation example for you with a little explanation. Does this help?

Comment: I am really really sorry, but I don't seem to get how, upon loading the pop up, I can apply the transition css.

Comment: @tabby When you say "load the pop up", does it not exist in the DOM at all until a certain moment, or does it begin in the DOM? How is the popup created?

Comment: It does not exist.  That's why I do a upgradeDom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188331/discussion-between-andy-hoffman-and-tabby).